# Separate one column in multiple column in teradata studio

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table with one column. Every row is like this:
Name|surname|Address|date

But I want separate this column in 4 columns, one for each variable.

How Can I make it in terastudio with sql??

I expect that this row example:

```
String

Lucas|Smith|Times square|10/12/2023
```

become:

```
Name  Surname Address       Date

Lucas Smith   Times square  10/12/23
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `STRTOK` function, which is available in Teradata. here how you can do this

```
SELECT
  STRTOK(your_column, '|', 1) AS Name,
  STRTOK(your_column, '|', 2) AS Surname,
  STRTOK(your_column, '|', 3) AS Address,
  STRTOK(your_column, '|', 4) AS Date
FROM your_table;
```

`STRTOK` is used to split the `your_column` into multiple columns based on the delimiter `|` and the third argument (e.g., 1, 2, 3, and 4) in each `STRTOK` function call specifies which part of the split value to extract into the separate columns.

Comment: you can take a look at this for more understanding : https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/strtok_split_to_table

Comment: @dnoeth  i updated my answer based on your comment